# Prolog: find a supplier who supply all parts

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog. These are my facts.

part_cost(Part, Supplier)

```
part_cost(top_tube ,cinelli).
part_cost(top_tube ,columbus).
part_cost(down_tube ,columbus).
part_cost(head_tube ,cinelli).
part_cost(head_tube ,columbus).
part_cost(seat_mast ,cinelli).
part_cost(seat_mast ,columbus).
```

I want to find a supplier who supplies all kinds of parts, which is actually columbus.

I don't know how to say "all" in Prolog language.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**

Thank you, @Ankur and @Sergey Dymchenko. Your list approach inspired me! I can write rules:

```
supplyAllParts(Supplier, []):-true.

supplyAllParts(Supplier, [Part|PartRest]) :- 
    part_cost(Part, Supplier, _, _),
    supplyAllParts(Supplier, PartRest).
```

and call it by

```
?- supplyAllParts(S,[top_tube, down_tube, head_tube, seat_mast]).
S = columbus.
```

Now can Prolog dynamically find the part list ([top_tube, down_tube, head_tube, seat_mast]) from the facts rather than I manually provide it?

Comment: "Now can Prolog dynamically find the part list" - that's exactly what code from @Ankur answer does: `setof(P,S^part_cost(P,S),R)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
supplies([],_).
supplies([H|T],S) :- part_cost(H,S), supplies(T,S).

| ?- setof(P,S^part_cost(P,S),R), supplies(R,Supplier).

R = [down_tube,head_tube,seat_mast,top_tube]
Supplier = columbus
```

Comment: I will prefer define another predicate `s(Supplier) :- setof(P,S^part_cost(P,S),R), supplies(R,Supplier)`. so that we can use `s` directly.

Comment: @LoveRight: Sure, the code example was just to show the concept

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably need to define a notion of "all parts" manually, because maybe there is some kind of "bottom_super_gravitsapa", that no one has:

```
% store in sorted order, to compare with setof results later
sort([top_tube, down_tube, head_tube, seat_mast], AllParts)
```

To get a list of all parts for every supplier we can use `setof/3`:

```
?- setof(Part, part_cost(Part, Supplier), Parts).
setof(Part, part_cost(Part, Supplier), Parts).
Supplier = cinelli
Parts = [head_tube,seat_mast,top_tube] ?;
Supplier = columbus
Parts = [down_tube,head_tube,seat_mast,top_tube]
yes
```

And now just add a condition that list of parts for a specific supplier and AllParts are the same:

```
Parts == AllParts
```

If you don't want to define AllParts manually and assume that there is a supplier for every possible part, you can use another `setof` to get AllParts from the facts before the main `setof`.

Answer (score 1):

`all` is a big word, in any language, and what it means varies so much... Down to the earth  , in Prolog we have [findall](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=allsolutions)/3 family, that outputs a list with all patterns we instruct to extract from *succeeded* queries. The output list then is further processed ... But for your case, library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) is more handy:

```
supplies_all(Supplier) :-
    aggregate(max(N,S), count_part_cost(S,N), max(_, Supplier)).

count_part_cost(S,N) :-
    aggregate(count, P^part_cost(P,S), N).
```

I used a service predicate count_part_cost/2, just to keep the main one clear...
If you try to 'inline' them, beware to variables usage. Study variables quantification until you are comfortable with it.

*edit* As noted by Sergey, my code is not correct. Here is my bet for a more appropriate definition:

```
supplies_all(Supplier) :-
    setof(P, S^part_cost(P,S), Ps),
    setof(P, part_cost(P,Supplier), Ps).
```

I think it highlights well what I intended above recommending about studying variable quantification...

*edit* another possible definition, less costly but with redundant multiple solution (well, we have setof for that...)

```
supplies_all(Supplier) :-
    % peek any Supplier from catalog
    part_cost(_,Supplier),
    % check it has all parts available
    forall(part_cost(P,_), part_cost(P,Supplier)).
```

Comment: If supplier 'a' has only part 'a', and supplier 'b' has only part 'b', correct logic is to fail, not to return 'a' as you program.